# Looking at git diff --name-status, how can I tell that a file has been renamed?

Tags: git

I have a script that uses `git diff --name-status` to find the differences between a given branch and the `master` branch, and perform various actions depending on how each file changed.

Git does not track renames. While it knows that a file has been renamed when you stage the commit, `git diff --name-status` only shows that the old name has been deleted and the new name has been added. This is a problem for me, as I would like to take additional steps with my script for files that have been renamed.

Given the name of a file that has been added, how can I tell whether the file is entirely new or a rename of another file (and if it is a rename, what was its previous name)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Git does not track renames.

This is true!  But ...

> While it knows that a file has been renamed when you stage the commit,

... this, in fact, is not quite true: Git is simply *guessing*; `git mv` does not record the rename, and you can manually rename or copy the file, then just `git rm --cached` the old path and `git add` the new one (in either order), to the same effect.

> `git diff --name-status` only shows that the old name has been deleted and the new name has been added.

You can get `git diff` to make the *same* guesses as `git status` by turning on *rename detection*.  In fact, `git status` simply runs `git diff` with rename detection turned on, and some additional speeding-up options (e.g., telling `git diff` that it should not bother to attempt to produce a diff, just the `--name-status` info, which of course is also the case when you use `--name-status`).

To enable rename detection when running `git diff`:

- add `-M` or `--find-renames` to the command line, or
- set `diff.renames` to `true` (or even `copies`) in your configuration, or
- upgrade to Git version 2.9 or later, where it defaults to enabled.

See also the descriptions of `-M`, `-C`, and `-B` in [the `git diff` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html), and the other configurable `diff.*` values in [`git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).  (I keep `diff.renameLimit` set to 0, for instance.)

Comment: I used "knows" for a loose definition of "knows". I realize that it's not recorded anywhere.

Comment: I suspect that, but I figured it's best to be explicit, especially if others come across this later.